# Can I Include author login in post class?

Tags: author, author-template

How can I include author nicename in post class by using `post_class` filter? I want to   add `author-AuthorLogin` class in post class so that I can apply styles based on author name. Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it pretty easily using [`get_the_author_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/) function and [`post_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_class/) filter:

```
function add_author_nicename_to_post_class( $classes, $class, $post_id ) {
    $classes[] = get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename' );

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'post_class', 'add_author_nicename_to_post_class', 10, 3 );
```